# Is there a way to use the start of a row in Excel in Python if the beginning row of a column is not always the same?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am trying to convert to Python from Excel, and I am wondering if there is a way to write the 'start row' of a column in Excel in Python, if the user can choose a different start row every time.

For example, one can use "sheet.nrows" to find the end row of a column.

```
for row in range(1,sheet.nrows):
```

I want to know if I can do somethings like:

```
for row in range(sheet.startrow, sheet.nrows)
```

Here is part of my excel doc. The user should be able to enter the starting date next to the corresponding day of the week. Whichever row the user chooses to place the starting date in, should be the beginning row for the loop in Python.
[Excel Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rql3u.png)

Comment: You can slice a column: `https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.col_slice`

Comment: What does slicing a column do exactly?

Comment: Well, I guess you can then do something like `for row in sheet.col_slice(start,end)`.

Comment: I'm confused as to what I would put for the "start" if I don't know what the start is?

Comment: It is the index of the start row which the user has chosen. You haven't explained *how* user selects the start row.

Comment: I've just updated the question to try to be more clear. The user chooses the starting row by entering the starting date in that specific row.

Comment: I see, this makes it much more clear. Why can't you simply iterate over the rows and skip them if they are empty? Are there going to be that many rows?

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was the best way to do it, but I'll just do it, thank you!